# Spark Dataframe show not generating a DAG

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate a dataframe by using toDF function like this [image]

When I see the Spark UI , after running the df.show action , I don't see any DAG , why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is in memory with *no parallelization* called; there is a Spark optimization  that can do it immediately where `Seq` is used to create a `dataframe`.

The same via this:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(1 until 5).toDF("a")
```

does produce Job / DAG as workers, distribution is involved.